# ¿Por qué la consola no me muestra las demás carpetas de /Documents al utilizar el comando "dir"?

Tags: rutas, consola

Estoy intentando acceder a la carpeta "CODER MATE" dentro de "Documents", pero al intentar ver las carpetas dentro de la ruta, me muestra todo el directorio vacío

[image: Captura de pantalla de lo anterior]

Comment: Y estás totalmente seguro que la ruta del terminal es la misma que estás mostrando en el explorador?

Comment: No soy usuario de Windows, pero creo que si pulsas sobre la casilla donde aparece `This...>Docu` en la parte superior del explorador te aparece la ruta donde realmente está y así puedes verificar si son la misma.

Comment: @masterguru tenías razón! La carpeta, sin darme cuenta, estaba almacenada en "One Drive", no en "Documents". 

Esta era la ruta de la carpeta:
C:\Users\mateo\OneDrive\Documentos\CODER MATE

Comment: je, me alegro que te haya servido... hace años que no uso windows (desde el XP) pero eso veo que aun lo conservan :-)